# Datastructure for efficient subset/supreset finding among multiple sets

Tags: data-structures, hash

The task is following.
We have multiple data in form of typized tuples, like (a,b,c) , (a,b), (b,c)  etc.
The task is, to find some datastructure for efficient hashing of this data.
For example, if you take common hash-set, you can check if the (a,b,c)  exist by the hash code of (a,b,c)
The task is to get all subsets/ supersets of some tuple - for example, from (a,b) you know that there is entry (a,b,c) as superset or  if you have (a,b,c) you know that (b,c,) is a sub set.
Currently, i guess it may be related to the prefix tree, but it is not exactly for this task, since there can be any combination of elements in a subset, by what you need to find the whole set.